# How to get rid of "WARNING: no homepage content found in homepage.md"?

Tags: html, css, npm, documentation, knyle-style-sheet

I'm getting started with KSS using [CSS in Depth](http://link.library.eui.eu/portal/CSS-in-depth-Keith-J.-Grant/CyyWsjIGOaQ/) by Keith Grant as a reference.

At 10.1.4, the author writes

> Inside the css directory, create a new file at css/homepage.md. This will be a file in markdown that serves as an introduction to the pattern library. Copy this listing into the file.
>
> ```
> # Pattern library
>
> Page heading This is a collection of all the modules in our stylesheet. You may use any of these
> modules when constructing a page.
> ```
>
> Now run `npm run build` and the warning about home page content should be gone.

The point is that the warning is not gone for me,

```
WARNING: no homepage content found in homepage.md.
```

and indeed opening `docs/index.html` in the browser shows the content of the directory.

In case it might be related, here's the full output of the `npm run kss` command:

```
> simplemodule@1.0.0 kss
> kss --config kss-config.json

Version 9 of Highlight.js has reached EOL and is no longer supported.
Please upgrade or ask whatever dependency you are using to upgrade.
https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2877
WARNING: no homepage content found in homepage.md
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.For details,please refer to the official demo [homepage.md](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bipL1.jpg)

note:The homepage.md file should be placed at the project root directory

[to visit official demo](https://github.com/kss-node/kss-node/tree/master/demo)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).